# play ebean's Date field format after Json.toJson()

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have problem with proper formatting Date field in Ebean model when I'm trying to return JSON in Controller method result

```
ok(Json.toJson(userObj));
```

My code example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq")
    public Integer id;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    public Date last_login;
...
}
```

Table is in postgresql database - field last_login is timestamp.

Json result is:

```
{"id":202,"last_login":1386775797494,...}
```

Can somebody explain me how to make it work?

Best regards,
Lukas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching all over the internet I found two solutions:

1.Create custom serializer like:

JsonDateSerializer class:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public void serialize(
            Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        jgen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

and annotate field in Model:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date last_login;
```

This solution is not flexible becouse you can't put second parameter with date format in @JsonSerialize annotation so you have to create next serialization class if you want have couple of date formats.

2.@JsonFormat

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Here you can define pattern in annotation so is more flexible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`Json.toJson(object)` uses Jackson which accepts a Mapper, in your case the answer it would be:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    mapper.setDateFormat(outputFormat);
    Json.setObjectMapper(mapper);   
    return ok(Json.toJson(object));
```

Then you can wrap this for future ocassions.